# How to pass arguments to a function in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am having the following function:

```
Future<List<expense>> getExpenseDateWise(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate) async {
final db = await database;
var expenses = await db
    .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= ? AND DATE(DATETIME) <= ?',
['$FromDate','$ToDate']);

List<expense> expensesList = List<expense>();
expenses.forEach((currentExpense) {
  expense expenses = expense.fromMap(currentExpense);
  expensesList.add(expenses);
});
return expensesList;
}
```

And the above function requires 2 arguments.

I am calling the above function in a following way:

```
 class dateWiseList extends StatefulWidget {
  final DateTime fromDate;
  final DateTime toDate;

  dateWiseList({this.fromDate, this.toDate});
 @override
 _dateWiseListState createState() => _dateWiseListState();
 }


class _dateWiseListState extends State<dateWiseList> {
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenseDateWise(// <----------1----------> //).then(
      (expenseList) {
    BlocProvider.of<ExpenseBloc>(context).add(SetDates(expenseList));
  },
 );
}
```

In **<----------1---------->** I need to pass the two arguments. I don't know how to do it please help me.

The function getExpenseDateWise is used for fetching data records between two dates selected by the user in a different form. That's why I have called those values using dateWiseList({this.fromDate, this.toDate});.
Thanks for your replies

Comment: How do you are calling the dataWiseList screen from the other screen?

Comment: There is another class in its body i have called it shall I copy the code over here?

Comment: Are you already passing the arguments from the other screnn?

Comment: If yes, you just need to like this DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenseDateWise(widget.fromDate, widget.toDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try widget.fromDate and widget.toDate. Coz I'm seeing you're using a stateful widget.

If your function takes positional arguments, eg
Future doSomething(String name, Bool jerk) {
Lots of code
}

Then when calling it inside a stateful widget, while using some arguments you passed to that widget, do tgis
blah blah = doSomething(widget.argument1, widget.argument2)

If it's not positional arguments, eg
Future doSomething({String name, Bool jerk} ) {
Lots of code
}

, then it's gonna be
blah blah = doSomething(
name: widget.argument1, jerk: widget.argument2)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the starting date and the end date to filter your data

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DtaeTime yesterday = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:1));
DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenseDateWise(yesterday, now).then(.........)
```

you can treat flutter functions just like any other functions

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But these arguments are not from this class they are from another form which i am calling in this class and getExpenseDateWise is a function which gives the data between two dates saved in the sqlite database.

Comment: I see, then you can simply use widget.fromDate, widget.toDate. if this worked for you tell me so I edit my answer